# 90s book, may have "Sleeping Dragon" in title

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

The book is about random people being transported to an alternate world. In the instance of the book its a neighborhood that is transported.

When the people come outside after they realize they been transported, they are met by a guy peddling ice cream and he tells them some info.

If I remember correctly they are brought to this place as food for powerful beings of magic. Each time people are transported one person in the group is imbued with powers that make them strong as the beings wanting to feed on them.

Some of the members of the neighborhood escape and link up with a militia from the 20s or earlier, suggesting the people are taken from multiple time lines.

Comment: Crouching Hobbit, Sleeping Dragon. No, wait...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dragon Sleeping** by Craig Shaw Gardner (1995)

Pursuing an ordinary life in 1967 Chestnut Circle, seventeen-year-old Nick Blake is astonished when his world is transformed by a fierce magical storm, forcing Nick to lead his neighbors into the heart of a sorcerer's conflict.

Contrasted with these "normal" folk is a singular supporting cast: rival "brother wizards" named Nunn and Obar, a race of beings called the Anno and several other sentient characters...

"Ice cream? You're the ice cream man?" Bobby started to laugh. Apparently, he thought the idea of an ice-cream-dispensing wizard was great.

Covers: https://www.librarything.com/work/369514/covers